# Clarification on /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, server

Can anyone explain what the following command in /etc/network/interfaces do?

```
up ip link set dev $IFACE up
```

I understand the `ip link` command but what is the `up` at the beginning of the line doing? Is it linking the `up` command to the rest of the `ip link set dev $IFACE up` command?

Answer (score 2):

From [`man interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html):

```
IFACE OPTIONS
   The following "command" options are  available  for  every  family  and
   method.   Each of these options can be given multiple times in a single
   stanza, in which case the commands are executed in the order  in  which
   they  appear  in  the stanza.  (You can ensure a command never fails by
   suffixing them with "|| true".)

   pre-up command
          Run command before bringing the interface up.  If  this  command
          fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
          configured, prints an error message, and exits  with  status  0.
          This behavior may change in the future.

   up command

   post-up command
          Run  command  after  bringing the interface up.  If this command
          fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
          configured  (even  though it has really been configured), prints
          an error message, and exits with status 0.   This  behavior  may
          change in the future.

...
There  exists  for  each  of  the  above  mentioned options a directory
/etc/network/if-<option>.d/ the scripts in which are run (with no argu‐
ments)  using  run-parts(8) after the option itself has been processed.
Please note that as post-up and pre-down are aliases, no files  in  the
corresponding  directories  are  processed.  Please use if-up.d and if-
down.d directories instead.
```

So, the `up` at the beginning is used to indicate that the command is to be run after the interface is up.